# MAC address spoof of a wifi connected device, not the network interface of the PC

Tags: wifi, mac-address, spoofing

Some devices are known to data hosts by their MAC. If you physically replace that device and it has a new MAC the host will not accept the data. All the router will do is spoof the network interface card MAC, not the WIFI connected device's MAC.

Is there any way to accomplish this task? Use case is a weather transmitting station that's connected to a router and the data sent to a host. I've considered using a Pi and a connected router to subnet the weather station but have been unable to find any reference to spoofing the WIFI station's MAC.

Comment: *"to data hosts by their MAC"* *"the host will not accept the data"* - erm, that's hard to understand.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question. In particular, describe which task you want to accomplish. The way it is written now, it looks like you want to do something with your router, but why are you posting it in the Unix forum then?